# checking the last word in a textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

i have an access form consisting of a textbox , i need to check the last word of it and if this word is one of many words (array or a table column ) do an action , and this check will occurs in after_update event , something like

```
Private Sub textbox_AfterUpdate()

 Dim txt As String
 Dim lastword As String

  txt = TextBox.Value

 lastword= Right(txt, Len(txt) - InStrRev(txt, " "))

 if lastword in (array() or column in a table) then

    ' do an action

 End If

 End Sub
```

we can also us an external function , could you help me with it ??

Comment: How can a word in a textbox be an array or column of a table? It's probably me but I don't understand what you mean with this...

Comment: no i have many words to check against so i will put them in an array , firstly i will extract the last word in the text field and i will compare this word to an array contains many other words

Comment: You only need a few functions to do this. Most important is to take certain validation into account. What will happen for example if the last word appears behind a dot or comma without space? There you got your first bug.

Comment: no it is a standard text and will never has comma or any other character only space don't worry, could u help me with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got the function for the last word already... Now for the search in an array and table use this:

```
Function isInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

and

```
Function isColumnName(stringToBeFound As String, tableName As String) As Boolean
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(tableName)
    isColumnName = False
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    do until rs1.EOF
        if rs1.Fields.Item(0).Value = stringToBeFound then
            isColumnName = true
            exit loop
        end if
        rs1.moveNext
    loop
    Set fld = Nothing
End Function
```

usage:

```
if isInArray(lastWord, youArray) or isColumnName(lastWord, "yourTable")
    MsgBox "The word is already used!"
end if
```

Comment: thank you , your functions  is working well  but you have to modify it because in case of iscolumnname() it works only with fields names in the table while i need it to work with the first column records not field name , also you have to add Dim db As Database and
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset in the beginning of this function , im waiting your modifications to start working with it , thank you for your great effort

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Dim txtStr As String
    Dim vWords, v
    txtStr = TextBox1.Text
    If InStr(txtStr, " ") > 0 Then
        txtStr = Right(txtStr, Len(txt) - InStrRev(txt, " "))
    End If
    vWords = Split("word1 word2 word3 word4", " ") ' fill vWords with the words you need
    For Each v In vWords
        If v = txtStr Then
            ' do an action
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You said you have your data in an "array or a table column". So which one is true?

Comment: yes i mean an access table not excel table , i can make external excel table but i don't know how to use it in this case

Comment: If you already have your data in an array, you don't need anything else. Just take the array and replace "vWords" in my example with it. It would be very helpful, if you edit your question and insert how you retrieve the words you need...

Comment: sorry im not good with vba and i wanted someone to helping me with it , i dont know how to put my words in an array and use it , suppose that my array is  array(word1,word2,word3,word4,.....) how can i use it in vword variable ???

Comment: You don't even give more information? What is the name of the tables, columns, etc.? How should we help, if there is no information?

Comment: put any example and i will replace it with my own